# Mysql - when trying to UPDATE a timestamp column. It fails to update

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I think I may have encountered a bug in mysql, or is it just me doing it wrong.

I've been using the same specific queries for the last four months and just today it stopped working somehow. I can't see the problem.

I'm executing these queries in the mysql console it works great, and the field is being updated. but when these queries are being executed by PHP it fails.

After insertion of a record into a table(with two timestamp fields), I'm trying to update a specific timestamp column.

But unfortunately it fails to update the column.

The query goes well(no errors), but still the value in the timestamp column stays the same. That's weird, cause when I'm leaving the initial column value as NULL, the update query succeed.

Columns :

```
START_DATETIME, END_DATETIME - are "timestamp" type.
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(START_DATETIME, END_DATETIME, RESPONSE) 
VALUES(NOW(), NOW(), 'STARTED')
```

Insert is done successfully. id is 123

The update query is normal like any other query:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET END_DATETIME = NOW(), RESPONSE='ENDED'
WHERE ID = 123
```

Update fails, `END_DATETIME` doesn't get the `NOW()` value.

Can be reproduced with this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
(
    id int auto_increment, 
    start_datetime timestamp, 
    end_datetime timestamp, 
    response varchar(100), 

    primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: In fact the END_DATETIME gets the NOW() value. Unfortunately the START_DATETIME gets the same. So far I have no explanation for this, though.

Comment: Hi guys, i think you missed my point. The real problem isn't in the default values of START_DATETIME (it has a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) The problem is in the END_DATETIME column that's being initialized in the INSERT query, Couldn't be updated to a different value -later-.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have defined the first timestamp column (the `START_DATETIME` one) to be auto-inserted and auto-updated with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value (which is the same as `NOW()`.

Notice that if you don't explicitedly state anything about the `TIMESTAMP` columns in the `CREATE TABLE` script, the **first** one of them gets by default this behaviour/attributes. Read the MySQL documentation about this [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html), where it states:

> - With neither `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` nor `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it is the same as specifying both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

So, if you do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName`, you'll have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
( ...
, START_DATETIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
                   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
, ...
) ;
```

You should alter the column definition to not be auto_updated, if you don't want this behaviour:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
  MODIFY COLUMN  
    START_DATETIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
                     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Comment: Edited the question to include a `CREATE TABLE` with which it can be reproduced. No `ON UPDATE` or whatever.

Comment: See my edit. Try the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName ;` statement.

Comment: Hi guys, i think you missed my point. The real problem isn't in the default values of START_DATETIME (it has a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) The problem is in the END_DATETIME column that's being initialized in the INSERT query, Couldn't be updated to a different value -later-.

Comment: Please run: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = 123;`, then `UPDATE table1 SET END_DATETIME = NOW(), RESPONSE='ENDED' WHERE ID = 123;`, then again `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = 123;` and shows us the outputs you get.

Comment: :) it's the same initial date. that's the problem.
Looks like the update query skips that column.
That is why I assumed there is a bug in mysql.
When i run that query from console it works fine!.

Comment: Oh, why can't you just show us the data? Even just this one (timestamp) column? And we are still waiting for the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` output. Help us to help you.

Comment: I would like to explain the phenomena:
At the beggining of a process a record is being inserted, with two timestamp field and with same value (NOW()).
After a while when the process ends, the second field (END_TIMESTAMP) needs to be updated. but it fails and the initial value stays the same.

for 4 months it ran normal, but yesterday some customers alerted me about the phenomena. so i examined the phenomena.

When i haven't managed to find a good reason for that, I refered to you guys...

Comment: Looks like the bug can't be reproduced. therefore I now sure that this was a bug in the Mysql.

Answer (score 2):

After looking into this more this is what I'd expect if the first table has ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as it is being automatically set by the update to the second record.

I don't think that this can have been working previously;

to fix it:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
    CHANGE COLUMN start_datetime start_datetime TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER id,
    CHANGE COLUMN end_datetime end_datetime TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER start_datetime;
```

If you want date time values the TIMESTAMP isn't much good for this as it is useful for auto-updating values as the TIMESTAMP data type offers automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time. For more information, see [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

If you need a field you can manage yourself then one of the other types

- DATE
- DATETIME

may be more appropriate, see [11.3.1. The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Er, as explained in the manual page to which you link, automatic intialisation/update of `TIMESTAMP` columns is *optional*.  And in any event, can be overridden in the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` command.

Comment: Hi Richard, thnx for your fast reply. I've been using the same specific queries for the last four months and just today it stoped working somehow.
I don't see the problem. If i'm executing these qureies in the mysql console it works great, and the field is being updated. but when these queries are being executed by php it fails.
is there any problem inserting NOW() value into a timestamp?
I could use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP....

Comment: There is no error during the execute. I wish there was. so i could point the problem

Comment: revised again after doing more tests it is clear that the first field TIMESTAMP is being set as a result of ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @Richard: How did you "revise"? It was not your question!

Comment: @ypercube I meant that I revised my answer in light of new information from the OP

Comment: @Richard: Oh, ok, I see now. We've come to the same conclusion but I'm not sure at all if that was the issue. This question has confused me a lot. Comments, editions by others (adding scripts from no-where ...)

Comment: @ypercube agree with you - confused me also. I can't help thinking that these fields are DATETIME rather than TIMESTAMP and then the problem wouldn't have occurred

Comment: Yeah, datetimes have neither auto insert nor auto update in MySQL. But it's a useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with timestamp type, If you change both the column to datetime, you will get what you are expecting